# Ukranian зозуля cuckoo

Tags: historical-linguistics, indo-european

I unfortunately did not find the etymology of Ukranian word зозуля zozúlja cuckoo. May it be a satemization ?

Comment: Have you looked in Vasmer? He lists a number of cognates under _зегзица_

Comment: I can not good enough read Russian texts.

Comment: there are german editions of Vasmer, I believe, just not as widely available online.

Answer (score 6):

As Jk wrote in his answer, the regular sound changes stop working regularly when it comes to onomatopoetic words. However, it does not mean that the sound changes do not occur and cannot be researched.

To give you some data points, here is the article from
[Vasmer's etymological dictionary](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/response.cgi?root=%2Fusr%2Flocal%2Fshare%2Fstarling%2Fmorpho&morpho=1&basename=morpho%5Cvasmer%5Cvasmer&first=1&off=&text_word=%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B7%D0%B8%CC%81%D1%86%D0%B0) which lists some possible cognates from Slavic, Baltic and Germanic languages. (I have translated the language names and key words from  Russian to English, but not the references)

> WORD: *зегзи́ца*
>
> GENERAL: "cuckoo", dialectal *жегозу́ля*, *заго́за* (Novgorod), *заго́ска*, *зазу́ля*, *зозу́ля*, Ukrainian  *зегзи́ця, зезу́ля*, Belr. *зозу́ля, зязю́ля*, 
>   Old East Slavic *зегзица* (СПИ), *зогзица* (Срезн. I, 994), also *жегъзуля* (Толк. Палея; см. Соболевский, Лекции 143), Chech *žežhule*, Slovakian *žežhulica,* Polish *gżegżóɫka*.
>
> ORIGIN: Pra-slavic **žеgъzа* with various distant assimilations; cognate with Lithuanian *gegužė̃*, hence *gegà, gẽgė*, Latvian *dzęguze*, Old Prussian *geguse*, further: Old Icelandic *gaukr*, Old High German *gouh*; see Меіllet МSL 12, 213 и сл.; Trautmann ВSW 81; Аltpreuss.Sprd. 336; М.--Э. 1, 539 and futher.
>   There is no reason to assume borrowing from West Slavic into Russian, contrary to Bulakhovsky (ОЛЯ, 7, 108). Doubts regarding the affiliation of the
>   Old Icelandic *gaukr* see Holthäusen, ZfslPh 24, 451.

As one can see, palatalisation might play a role transforming former *g* into *z* or *ž*, but in that case it happened in the Balto-Slavic period, long after satemization.

Answer (score 1):

Words like *cuckoo* or *зозуля zozúlja* are onomatopoetic and thus impossible to tract by historical linguistic methods. Because they are linked to natural sounds (in this case the call of the bird) they do not follow the regular sound laws. They also tend to be re-created anew *ex nihilo* (i.e., just from the natural sounds they are imitating).

**TL;DR** Nothing conclusive can be said about this one.